# Overriding toString prototype inside object declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js

There was a question on here already about overriding `toString` and the answer is this:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return "this is Foo";
}
```

However my question is:

Is there a way to put this prototype override INSIDE of the object declaration like so:

```
function Foo() {
    Foo.prototype.toString = function(){
        return "this is Foo";
    }
}
```

Or like so:

```
var Foo =  {
Foo.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "this is Foo";
   }
}
```

It's really weird/annoying to have to put the prototype outside of the object declaration, but maybe this is a quirk of JavaScript. I have been wondering this for awhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are searching for bellow

```
function Foo() {
    this.toString = function() {
        return "this is Foo";
    }
}
```

**Note:- A drawback of this way is that the method `toString()` is recreated every time you create a new instance of `Foo`.**

Comment: This makes each instance of `Foo` have its own `toString` function, losing all benefits of object prototypes.

Comment: @TedHopp I got you, but I think this is the answer for question.

Comment: @AlexMills I didn't get what do you mean?

Comment: @Mritunjay I meant: what about declaring an object with var foo = {} instead of declaring the object with function Foo(){}.

Comment: @TedHopp can you elaborate on what you mean? In most OO languages, you have to override methods like toString() to get what you want for each instance. I don't see what benefits of object prototypes are lost by doing what Mritunjay suggests in this answer.

Comment: @AlexMills - With this approach, every time a new `Foo` object is created, a new `Function` object is created as well and assigned to the `toString` property of the just-created `Foo` object. All these `toString` function objects behave identically, but they are all distinct objects, which is a considerable waste. That's a major reason why prototypes exist. With prototypes, a single `Function` object is created and assigned to the `toString` property of the prototype for `Foo`. Then when a new `Foo` object is created, it inherits through its prototype that single `toString` implementation.

Comment: hmmm, I think I follow, let me think about it

Answer (score 10):

As Ted Hopp mentions, there is no other way to do this *yet*. In ECMAScript 6 you will be able to use the `class` syntax, which is just syntactict sugar for constuctor functions and prototypes:

```
class Foo {
  toString() { ... }
}
```

For object literals, there will also be a shorthand:

```
var foo = {
  __proto__: {
    toString() {...}
  }
};
```

The special `__proto__` declaration allows you to define the prototype inside the object literal. However, since the protoype is only really useful when it is *shared* by multiple onjects, directly assigning the property to the object instead would be simpler in this case, and also works today already:

```
var foo = {
  toString: function() {},
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no good way to do what you want. The `Function` object `Foo` (which is usually an object constructor) doesn't exist until the declaration is evaluated, so there's no prototype available for assigning a `toString` property. Furthermore, the `toString` assignment won't be evaluated until the constructor is executed at least once.

In any case, you don't want to be initializing the `toString` property of the prototype inside the constructor because that will assign a new function for each instance of `Foo` that is created. You could test whether the prototype already has its own `toString` property already, but this makes the cure worse than the disease. Just stick to the recipe.

Comment: So what do you think about Felix's answer?

Comment: @Pacerier - Now that Ecmascript 6 is widely supported, I think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Foo() {
    return {
        toString: function () {
            return "this is foo";
        }
    };
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.toString());
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Then hat somebody got it wrong. This creates a labeled statement with an anonymous function. The function is discarded immediately.

Comment: An explanation of what you are doing and comparing it to Mritunjay's answer would certainly be good.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that because at the time you are referencing `Foo` inside the object, `Foo` hasn't been declared yet. You could try doing this instead.

```
var Foo = {}; //assign Foo to an empty object.
```

and then add various properties/methods to `Foo` using the `Object.defineProperties` and `Object.assign` depending on what you want.